# Can Facebook test apps receive ads_management extended permission from Ads API approved app?

Tags: facebook-apps, facebook-ads-api

When I create a test app from one that's been approved for the Facebook Ads API that test app doesn't receive the ads_api_extern feature.

Am I missing a setting or other way that I can make ads api requests using a test app?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, a test app doesn't inherit special permissions like access to the ads api

That would need to be whitelisted separately by whomever granted your existing app that access